# return function argument variables to main in c

Tags: function, arguments, program-entry-point

Apologies if this is stupid, but I made some simple code to get my point across. Namely it is this. If I use int x , y, from my main function as arguments, shouldn't I be able to use return() to export them back into the main function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*function prototype */
int add(int x, int y);

int
main()
{
 int x, y;
 printf("enter # to add ->\n");
 scanf("%d", &x);
 printf("enter # to add ->\n");
 scanf("%d", &y);

 /* function call */

 /* print statement 1 */
 printf("The sum is -> %d, x -> %d and y was-> %d \n", add(x, y)); 

 /*print statement 2 always is fine*/
 printf("The sum is -> %d", add(x,y));

 /* print statement 3 */
 printf(" the sum is -> %d, x-> %d, and y-> %d \n", add(x, y), x, y);
return(0);
}

/*function*/
int add(int x, int y)
{
 int sum;   
 sum = x+y;
 return(sum, x, y);
}
```

Sample
Print1 ex. If x,y input is 6,7 respectively I get "the sum is -> 13, x -> 6 and y was-> -1346575416". obviously there is something wrong with y..

Print3 ex. For this example is the easiest way to do it, but I need to know how to get out **any manipulated values of x,y by-the function**

I have tried renaming x,y vars in the function (i.e. xx=x, yy=y), adding them then using them in return(sum, xx, yy), but that did not help either.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why are you trying to return three values? C doesn't work that way.

Comment: I can think of many reasons "why", but I honestly didn't know one was the limit (inexperience)... I figured if you could pass in multiple values, multiple values could be returned. FYI I have found a way to do it, but it is disgusting and would never try rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

It is cannot be done in C, but you can try some methods, like using struct, or using pointer.
For example :

```
typedef struct _OP{
  int x, y, sum;
}Operate;

Operate add(Operate addOperation){
  addOperation.sum = addOperation.x + addOperation.y;
  return addOperation;
}

int main(){

Operate num, result;
num.x = 10;
num.y = 5;
result = add(num);
printf("x : %i, y : %i, sum : %i", result.x, result.y, result.sum);

return 0;

}
```

Hope it helps,